# Javascript array vs object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This might be a noob question for you guys but I just want to clarify something. I'm new to JS and I know that arrays are just objects with fields as indexes.

I have some lines of code here. The objective is pretty easy, is to pass a parameter function to an array and map it to another one.

My confusion is that the _obj is declared as an object with `_obj = {}`, and we have to do `_obj[obj.key] = obj.value` to map the keys and values. What is actually going around here?
It makes me feel like there are two nested arrays and it feels gross. I hope you understand me and I just need to know if there is another way or what actually is going on.

Stay at home guys!
Thanks in advance.

```
const objArray = [
    {key:1, value:10},
    {key:2, value:20},
    {key:3, value:30},
    {key:4, value:40}
];

const newArray = objArray.map(obj => {
    let _obj = {};
    _obj[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return _obj;
});

console.log(newArray);
//Array [Object { 1: 10 }, Object { 2: 20 }, Object { 3: 30 }, Object { 4: 40 }]
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? All I see is working code.

Comment: maybe you are confused by the value of `obj.key`, but it can be any string (all other types are converted to string, except *symbols*). the array is just a special form of an object (aka exotic object as the standard describes it) .

Comment: I did not say my code is not working. I was just trying to make my mind on js objects and arrays. Thanks Nina, your comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just need to know if there is another way or what actually is going
>   on.

When you do:

```
_obj[obj.key] = obj.value;
```

... you are setting a key/property on the object `_obj` to hold a particular value. In this case, the key you are setting is the value of `obj.key` and the value is `obj.value`. The values of `obj.key` and `obj.value` changes depending on what object you are iterated on in the `.map()` callback. For example, if you are looking at the first object in your array, `obj.key` would be `1` and `obj.value` would be `10`. Thus, doing `_obj[obj.key] = obj.value` would be equivalent to  `_obj[1] = 10`, which sets the key of `1` to have the value of `10` on the `_obj` object:

```
{
  1: 10
}
```

This process occurs for each object in your array.

As for a different approach, you could use [computed-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) names introduced in ES6 with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to return an object literal with the key property as the key for the new object literal and the value property and the actual value for the new object:

```js
const objArray = [
  {key:1, value:10},
  {key:2, value:20},
  {key:3, value:30},
  {key:4, value:40}
];

const newArray = objArray.map(({key, value}) => ({[key]: value}));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the precise explanation. Your alternative approach also looks simple and it's amazing!

Comment: @HalilBurakCetinkaya no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, just like java, everything that is not a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) is an object. Arrays are actually an object that just have some utility functions added in, such as the length attribute, and `.map`. To access a property, you can either do `obj.prop`, or use an arbitrary string like python's dictionaries like `obj["prop"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Array is special object, In which all key should be Number. The array has some pre-defined method, Which is made to iterate and perform similar operations. The array is linear and implements stack implementation. Array element could be any other object or Array.

**To understand:**

```js
const object = {
  1: "something",
  2: "something2"
}
const object2 = {
  "1_1": "something",
  "2_1": "something2"
}
// console.log(object[1])
// console.log(object[2])
// console.log(object2["2_1"]) // Key string
// console.log(object2["1_1"])

// object.forEach(console.log) // Error


const array = ["something", "something2"]
const array2 = []
array2["1_1"] = "something"
array2["2_1"] = "something2"

console.log(array[0]) // index start with 0, default
console.log(array[1])
console.log(array2["2_1"]) // Key string
console.log(array2["1_1"]) // Works

array.forEach(console.log) // No error, something 0 [ 'something', 'something2' ] something2 1 [ 'something', 'something2' ]
array2.forEach(console.log) // No error, // No output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the variant with reduce method:

```
const objArray = [
  {key:1, value:10},
  {key:2, value:20},
  {key:3, value:30},
  {key:4, value:40}
];

const newArray = objArray.reduce((acc, rec) => { return {...acc, [rec.key]: rec.value} }, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray))

// {"1":10,"2":20,"3":30,"4":40}
```